# Flow restrict to extend a class by assigment methods from callback

Tags: javascript, flowtype, flow-typed

StackOverflow community! The `$Subtype<>` utility allows to do a lot of weird stuff flowtyping. Now I need to escape old functionality  using the $Super utility and Generics. Literally flow spec is very brief, I couldn't find anything about how to extend an instance of a class with new methods. Please, help me to FlowFix .

I've tried a lot of tricks, but, look, I can't change a conduct aka usage of this function.

```
/* @flow */

class MainClass<C> {
    constructor(
        callback: (
            resolve: (result?: any) => void,
            reject: (error?: any) => void
        ) => mixed
    ): void {
        // Contructor things
    }
}

type ExtendedClass<D> = MainClass<D> & {
    resolve(D): void;
    reject(Error): void;
}

export function extended<D>(): ExtendedClass<D> {
    let resolve;
    let reject;
    const main: MainClass<D> = new MainClass((res, rej) => {
        resolve = res;
        reject = rej;
    });

    main.resolve = resolve;
    main.reject = reject;

    return main;
}
```

[Try this example](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjGBDAzrsAWWwEsA7AYR3wB4KA+MAb1QEgM4zcAXAJwFcM3OLwAUqMJKntsMGACNsGANYAuMOKlawrXgFNccGADc960ftz8Y3APzrsZAJ4BKMAF5GxuCQAmAGgltSV09ACs9IXM9Xl4RezBHVw8vH18grVY3TzAAWxIADz10rRd1bz9mINZWYGAwCk4+QWFeMG4AC3IAc1w2AF9UQdRuJwAHPTAAUQLuPTJfYqo8XBoAEUZ3IlJKalWNsAAyKtDDEz1RNbKwCt8AbgywfQihUSnYkWvbh+G9ArGRNwwFB+GQhCROGA-nMFsV1vRRNcZjDFr5lrQDiwQjA9EDLEZTA8tDi8eFItwHuxODw8jt1MRyOj9pswGQ9EgGbsVqILAZ-E9wtlGFjpPjzh4BbgidpQi8gVtntLJP0XA82LkdgA6MWmCU6vSUjXkbVkoR600U9BafTcfi8Mi08g-VBAA)

```
main.resolve = resolve;
          ^ Cannot assign `resolve` to `main.resolve` because property `resolve` is missing in `MainClass` [1].

    References:

    22:     const main: MainClass<D> = new MainClass((res, rej) => {
                     ^ [1]
```

Comment: This is the kind of thing where I'd usually just use `any` or `$FlowIgnore`, but I don't know if there is a better way.

Comment: Why not extend a class if you want to extend it
https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjGBDAzrsAWWwEsA7AYR3wB4KA+MAb1QEgM4zcAXAJwFcM3OLwAUqMJKntsMGACNsGANYAuMOKlawrXgFNccGADc960ftz8Y3dRQCUYALyNjcEgBMANBO2TdegBWekLmery8IuoAohEiji5gbp6+WqwJjAC2JAAeeh6pYI4s-qzAwGAUnHyCwrxg3AAW5ADmuGwAvqhdmNQE0TncemQe+VR4uDQAIox6g8MeBMTk47QzzL4cXDVCIqLFhVs8YAAOkTkAns7MHQDcvqxWJ+GioiIkLeSyAEoGRqZeMDvT5kH5BELcDIbUpnOCXAB0ln+emuwK+MF+hhMenufkksIR+mCQlRvA+6N+xO491YHXsuKkTRIuERf2x1wJF1ZWNMDMkTJZRIhHPOXKFQgZXUkbCR2PMUyhyQ8fLA4tsGlikV4ivcyu66DmJxE3DAUH4ZCEJE4YDmQxG+Wm9H2MXm9o8q0m6xKUn03H4vDIYDIeiQAzto3dfXuXSAA ?